# Converting Python into C and then compiling into an exe with Cython

Tags: python, c, compilation, cython

I've been struggling with Cython for a few hours and can't figure out how to get it to work properly
I've managed to convert my Python into C with this command

```
    Cython-0.21>cython.pyc --embed -o example.c example.py
```

But then I am clueless as what to do. I've tried to compile it with cl.exe and a gcc as other threads and posts on stackoverflow have suggested but I've just ran into problems everytime.

Could someone either point me in the right direction or give me an exampled and thorough guide to how to do this?

This command:

```
Cython-0.21>D:\Program\MinGW\bin\gcc -c -ID:\Program\Python2\include -o example.o example.c
```

Outputs that libgmp-10.dll is missing, which it isn't, I've googled on the subject and come up with nothing.

And this:

```
My edit:
cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -ID:\Program\Python2\include -Ipathtosourcelocation /Tnameofsource /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:D:\Program\Python2\libs /LIBPATH:D:\Program\Python2\PCbuild
Original command:
cl.exe  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Python31\include -Ic:\Python31\PC /Tcsmalltest1.c /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MACHINE:X86 /LIBPATH:c:\Python31\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Python31\PCbuild
```

I don't even understand. I tried changing everything within it to what seems to be the right thing, but I've just ran into problems, one being that when I try to compile it saids that my sourcefile does not exist, and another being that it's not a valid name and therefore it will skip the sourcefile parameter.

So could someone either provide me with another course of action or break these down for me? Alternatively fixing them where the error is?

[EDIT]
Partially solved, see my other reply.

Although, I still have an issue. When I open the program I get this: prntscr.com/4ull6p "An application has made an attempt to load the C Runtime library incorrectly."

What should I do?

Comment: if the .dll is not in either your $SYSTEM$ location, or in the local directory (i.e., it is visible to the command) then it will be seen as missing.  Note, system for Win 7 32 bit is syswow64, for 64 bit it is system32. (see details below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not address your problem, but make sure your files (i.e. .dlls) are located in the right place...

If using Windows 7 (you do not indicate) follow these locations:

[image]

***[From Here](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)***

Regarding source files being missing, make sure you are using complete path names in your command line arguments.  Example "c:\dir1\dir2\filename.c"

Some implementations include tools.  Such as this one to make getting your path variables easy: `numpy.get_include()`. See other examples ***[From Here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html)***

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own error in cl.exe.

What I had done was open visualstudio cli, and then ran cl.exe from there, but I needed to cd into the folder where the sourcefile was located.

And for the other reply, it's true. I just needed to move the DDL's to the folder of where I was already CD'd.

Comment: Although, I still have an issue. When I open the program I get this:
http://prntscr.com/4ull6p
"An application has made an attempt to load the C Runtime library incorrectly."